# Как правильно сделать метод принимающий модель?

Tags: php, symfony

Пытаюсь сделать REST. Нужен метод который будет сохранять модель переданную в POST запросе. Подскажите пожалуйста как это правильно делается в Symfony? Только начал его изучать еще ничего не знаю... Можно ли использовать для этого ту модель которую в базу сохраняю? Или надо отдельно какую-то модель-форму создавать? И как в нее данные загружать? Может вообще можно ее параметром метода указать (с указанием типа), а фреймворк сам сообразит как смаппить?

Comment: Изучи модуль forms. https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html в одном флаконе закрываешь и валидацию полей и добавление их в модель (если модель не сложная)

Comment: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-forms

Comment: @DmitryKozlov подсказывает формы и это отличное решение, однако в случае если у вас моделей не очень много. Представить себе что под каждую модель сидеть и писать формы - занятие весьма сомнительное. 
Я бы вам к дополнению Дмитрия рекомендовал бы (тем более мы говорим про REST) посмотреть на тему компонентов сериализации и валидации, ну или посмотреть бандл, реализующий функционал RESThttps://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html , однако я считаю что его документация крайне плоха.